# How do I test an inner function that is been looped over with jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking, jsdom, jest-dom

How do you test an inner function that is been looped over in jest?

Example I have:

index.js

```
const innerFunc = (type) => document.querySelector(`input[name="${type}"]`).value;
const anotherInnerFunc = (type) => document.querySelector(`input[name="${type}"]`).value = '';

const mainFunc = () => {
  const resultArray = [];
  // the document.querySelector('input[type="1 of those arrayTypes"]') on those inside functions
  const arrayTypes = ['name', 'email', 'card']

  for (const type of arrayTypes) {
    // innerFunc
    resultArray.push(innerFunc(type))
    // clearing the input fields
    anotherInnerFunc(type)
  }
  return resultArray;
}

module.exports = {
  mainFunc,
  innerFunc,
  anotherInnerFunc
}
```

and for index.test.js

```
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */
const indexFile = require('./index');
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');
const html = require('./duphtml.js');

let dom, window, document, inputName, inputEmail, inputCard;
describe('Testing the HTML FORM from index.html using JSDOM', () => {

  beforeAll(() => {
    dom = new JSDOM(html);
    window = dom.window;
    document= window.document;
    inputName = document.querySelector(`input[name="name"]`);
    inputName.value = 'FakeCC';
    inputEmail = document.querySelector(`input[name="email"]`);
    inputEmail.value = 'test@email.com';
    inputCard = document.querySelector(`input[name="card"]`);
    inputCard.value = '5457623898234113';
    // console.log(document.querySelector(`input[name="name"]`).value)
  });

  it('how do I test those inner functions?', () => {

    // Im a bit lost here searched around cant find anything to help me find the solution and I am out of ideas
    const inputArray = [inputName, inputEmail, inputCard];

    // how can I reach this end goal so those inside functions do working
    expect(indexFile.mainFunc()).toEqual(inputArray)
  })

})
```

How can I reach the final expect? And how would I pass in the three values of inputs I have defined inside the `beforeAll` block to perhaps those inside functions?

As the inside functions are returning null:

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

      110 | // Tested WORKS! check index.test.js
      111 | /* ----------------------------------- FORM SUBMISSION -------------------------------------- */
    > 112 | const newValue = (type) => document.querySelector(`input[name="${type}"]`).value;
```

this line:

```
dom = new JSDOM(html);
```

`html` is from another file I pasted the `index.html` into it as a string to have access to it inside the test file

duphtml.js

```
const html = `
<!doctype html>
  <main class="flex">
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <section class="modal-dialog">
      <form method="POST" onsubmit="mainFunc().bind(this); return false" class="flow" action="">
        <div class="flex">
          <label for="name">Name:</label>
          <!-- First and Surname (should have been specified on the user stories) -->
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name"/>
          <!-- <p>Enter a correct name</p> -->
        </div>
        <div class="flex">
          <label for="email">Email:</label>
          <input pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email"/>
          
        </div>
        <div class="flex">
          <label for="card">Card:</label>
          <input type="text" name="card" onkeyup="luhnAlgorithm(this)" id="card" placeholder="Enter a Proxy Credit Card Number"/>
          <img hidden src="./assets/other.png" id="imgCard" style="padding:5px;" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </section>
  </main>
`

module.exports = html;
```

Comment: Please add answers as answers rather than as part of the question :)

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

I have solved the problem if anyone has anything similar do look at this answer

Inside the beforeAll() After making the document and window variable from JSDOM I had to set them as a global var like this

```
global.window = window;
global.document = document;
```

Moreover I had to delete this config jsdocs

```
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */
```

As it was making my code not work.

I changed beforeAll() to beforeEach() but that is not that serious.

**So this fixed it**